# Android In App - How to check whether User has already purchased product?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app, developer-payload

I want to check based on email id, whether user installs application on two different devices with same email id then user need to purchase item once only. How to perform such functionality. Right now I went through Google's example but there is no such functionality.

And also what logic can be applied to generate payload? And how payload can be used to check whether item is purchased or not for a particular user?

Comment: Anybody has any ideas to implement the same...Please provide ASAP.